# I need help to make Popup in this fragment below

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have an activity.java which is contains some fragments like those below, and on one of these fragments I want to make a popup window. I tried a lot of things but all failed.

Now I am showing my code here to see if someone can help me.

Here is my fragment.java:

```java
public class Info extends Fragment {

public Info() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.kaynaklar_info, container, false);
}
```

Here is my fragment xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/kaynaklarinfo"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView3" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/pozitif"
        android:id="@+id/infonuniciresim" />
</ScrollView>
```

Here is my popup xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/popup_element"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:padding="10px"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/deneme"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Transfering data" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Status" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/server_status_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Awaiting answer..."
    android:paddingLeft="10sp" />
```

Comment: Like i said i am newbiew on this things i did not get anything from that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popup window in Android is called as [`AlertDialog`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) and you can see how to build a custom dialog [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/).

Comment: final Context context = this;
it is not working in a fragment

Comment: Try: final Context context = getContext();

Comment: or use getActivity()